# Error launching pgadmin in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, pgadmin

I installed pgadmin4 on xenial as it was mentioned in the site. I did as instructed, and the installation was successful, but, the following two errors cycle around and I can't launch pgadmin at all:

[image: error screenshots]

What is causing this and how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Is there a space between “chrome” and “%URL%”?   If not, try adding one.

Comment: @Scott, I've tried that, but the problem doesn't seem to be from there.

Comment: Try starting it from a console, then you should get a more complete error message.